# cannot compare a string to "y"

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to count how many y's in my code. Since you can see that I do have some y's in my file. but the counters are still zero. what am I doing wrong? (p.s I know they both are "if(word=="y")" I want to count n's too. shouldn't really matter here)

```
inline ifstream& read(ifstream& is, string f_name)
{
is.close();
is.clear();
is.open(f_name.c_str());
return is;
}

//main function
int main ()
{
string f_name=("dcl");
ifstream readfile;
read(readfile, f_name);
string temp, word;
istringstream istring;
int counter=0, total=0;
while(getline(readfile,temp))
{
    istring.str(temp);
    while(istring>>word)
    {
        cout<<word<<"_"<<endl;
        if(word=="y")
            ++counter;
        if(word=="y")
            ++total;
    }
    istring.clear();
}
cout<<counter<<" "<<total<<" "<<endl;
return 0;   
}
```

and my output is

```
Date_
9am_
Break_
Lunch_
Walk_
Break_
---------------------------------------------------_
11/09/11_
y_
y_
y_
y_ 
y_
_
0 0
```

my input codes:

```
//check list for daily activities
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;
//inline function
inline ofstream& write(ofstream& input, string& f_name); //write to a file function
inline void tofile(ofstream& w2file, const string& s);  //output format
//main function
int main ()
{
string f_name="dcl";
cout<<"date: "<<ends;
string temp;
cin>>temp;
ofstream checklist;
write(checklist,f_name);
tofile(checklist,temp);
cout<<"start the day at 9am? [y/n]"<<ends;
cin>>temp;
tofile(checklist,temp);
cout<<"a break every 1 hr? [y/n]: "<<ends;
cin>>temp;
tofile(checklist,temp);
cout<<"lunch at noon? [y/n]: "<<ends;
cin>>temp;
tofile(checklist,temp);
cout<<"20 min walk? [y/n]: "<<ends;
cin>>temp;
tofile(checklist,temp);
cout<<"a break every 1 hr in the afternoon? [y/n]: "<<ends;
cin>>temp;
tofile(checklist,temp);
checklist<<endl;
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}

inline ofstream& write(ofstream& input, string& f_name)
{
input.close();
input.clear();
input.open(f_name.c_str(),ofstream::app);
return input;
}

inline void tofile(ofstream& w2file, const string& s)
{
w2file<<s<<"\t"<<ends;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me (after adding the appropriate headers that is).  I stripped the _'s off your output to make a text file, compiled the program, and ran it and got a result of "5 5".

Comment: When I make the program compilable and populate the file with some "y" lines, I get "5 5 " as the final output as expected.

Comment: maybe it's my charactor encoding? when I open dcl with gedit. it has some weird boxes that have numbers in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `tofile` function in your program to generate the DCL file. When writing each line you're basically separating each field by a tab character, followed by a null character by doing `<< "\t" << ends;` and then later reading the line and using it with `istringstream` but `istringstream` separates by space characters. So, you need change `"\t"` to `" "` and drop the `<< ends`.

```
inline void tofile(ofstream& w2file, const string& s)
{
    w2file << s << " ";
}
```

Comment: As a side note you only need one if... You can do this: if( 0 == word.compare("y") ) ++counter, ++total;

Comment: still get 0 0; is it because I compiled it in linux? do I need to save it as a txt file? I just touch'ed dcl(file name)

Comment: I compiled your program as-is on a linux system and I get 5, 5. Can you show your original "dcl" file?

Comment: I think the problem is your program is not writing new line characters in the "dcl" file. change <<ends to <<endl

Comment: I want to keep the format like "11/09/11 y n y y y" if I change ends to endl, the output would be vertical, right?

Comment: Then change "ends" to " ", and remove the tab. istringstream seems to be space separated. I made this change in your program to generate the DCL file and it is working.

Comment: I delete the "ends" in "inline tofile" function and change all "ends" to "endl", it works. I think the problem was the "ends" in tofile. why this happened?

Comment: ends is a null character which will be the end of the string. istringstring separates by spaces, it does not look for null characters.

Comment: You may want to look at [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream/) and check out the [documentation on **ends**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/ends/)

Comment: `w2file.flush()` [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/)

Answer (score 2):

Try `std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), 'y')` to count the occurences of 'y' inside a word and accumulate that to a total counter.

Answer (score 0):

If I add the appropriate includes and a "using namespace std" to the beginning of your source and compile with g++, then run it against your output as the contents of the file "dcl", it prints "5 5" at the end -- i.e., your code works fine. Your input must be extremely peculiar somehow...